# Magento 2: Bulk update inventory

Tags: magento, magento2

Is it possible to make a bulk update for inventory on Magento 2?

Updating one by one throughout StockItemInterface is too slow.

Answer (score 2):

Since Magento 2.3 you can use new Multi-Source Inventory (MSI) which provides Bulk APIs for main source management operations, for example, the one you mentioned here is https://github.com/magento-engcom/msi/blob/2.3-develop/app/code/Magento/InventoryApi/Api/SourceItemsSaveInterface.php

Answer (score 0):

Sure! You should use a csv file with updated product data and do import using Magento import tool.

Comment: Magento import tool is not using bulk update. It is updating item by item and it is very slow when you need to update large quantities of products.

Comment: You can use magmi then, it's very fast.